# How to set up mulitple signatures for one account in Claws-Mail

Tags: email, claws

I'm new to Claws-Mail. Claws-Mail has GPG signature capability. This is for using digital signatures.  I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I'd like a *signature* that is automatically added to the end of an email that gives my name, address and phone number. I'd like to set up multiple signatures for an account if possible. I found in Configuration > Preferences for Current Account > Compose
[image: Account Preferences Dialog Box]

There was no .signature file so I created one in the specified directory using Libre Writer (the "edit" button didn't open an editor). The signature is automatically inserted to my emails. Is there a way or a plugin for setting up *multiple* signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked for the same thing and couldn't find it. I think the next best thing is to have multiple (almost) identical accounts with different signature settings.